# Feeding highchart with x and y values from ajax

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to feed my highchart from a database using ajax. From my ajax request, I want to return both x and y values (the x value is like that: year-week, ie 2020-16; the y value is a random number). My chart remains blank, I have a silent error that I cannot figure out. I'm pretty sure it comes from the strucure of the data returned by ajax, but I can't seem to fix it on my own.

Here's my javascript:

```
    var weekOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'weekContainer',
            type: 'column',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Last 52 weeks',
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        xAxis: {
            lineWidth: .5,
            tickWidth: 1,
            tickLength: 10,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Distance (miles)'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                },
            },
            allowDecimals: false,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            split: true,
            useHTML: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            valueSuffix: ' miles',
            formatter: '',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    symbol: "circle",
                    radius: 3,
                }
            }
        },
        lang: {
            noData: "No Data. Make sure at least one activity type is selected."
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '15px',
                color: '#303030'
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: ['viewFullscreen']
                }
            },
        },
        series: [{}],
    };


    //get series from ajax filtered by activity types
    $.ajax({
        url: "weekGetSeries.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            activityType: activityTypeSelected,
            dataToDisplay: dataToDisplay,
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (json) {
            weekOptions.series = json;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(weekOptions);
        }
    });
```

And here my ajax php file:

```
    <?php

        require 'dbConnection.php';

        $activityType = array(1,2,3,4,5);
        $dataToDisplay = "distance";
        $startingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-52 week', time()));
        $firstWeek = strtotime($startingDate);
        $conditionActivityType = ' WHERE startingTime >= "' . $startingDate . '" AND (type=' . implode(" OR type=",$activityType) . ')';
        $dataSerie = array("name" => "Weekly Stats","data" => array());

        for($i = 0; $i < 52; $i++){
            $nextWeek = strtotime('+'.$i.' week', $firstWeek);
            $dataSerie["data"][date("o",$nextWeek) . "-" . date("W",$nextWeek)] = 0;
        }

        $getActivities = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM activity" . $conditionActivityType . " ORDER BY startingTime ASC");
        if ($getActivities->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $getActivities->fetch_assoc()) {
                $date = substr($row["startingTime"],0,10);
                $date = strtotime($date);
                $week = date("W",$date);
                $category = date("Y-",$date).$week;
                $distance = ($row["distance"]);
                $movingTime = $row["movingTime"];
                $elapsedTime = $row["elapsedTime"];
                $totalElevationGain = ($row["totalElevationGain"])*3.28084;

                switch ($dataToDisplay) {

                    //distance
                    case "distance":
                        $dataSerie["data"][$category] += $distance;
                        break;

                    //Moving Time
                    case "movingTime":

                        break;

                    //Elapsed Time
                    case "elapsedTime":

                        break;

                    //elevation gain
                    case "totalElevationGain":

                        break;

                    //number activities
                    case "activities":

                        break;

                }
            }
        };

        $data = array();
        array_push($data,$dataSerie);

        echo json_encode($data);

    ?>
```

My ajax returns this:

[{"name":"Weekly Stats","data":{"2019-17":13184.4,"2019-18":73560.2,"2019-19":36899.4,"2019-20":0,"2019-21":38691.3,"2019-22":165127.8,"2019-23":188163.2,"2019-24":12888.5,"2019-25":60011.3,"2019-26":32585.2,"2019-27":12952.8,"2019-28":7944.8,"2019-29":79258.3,"2019-30":60885.2,"2019-31":0,"2019-32":0,"2019-33":0,"2019-34":0,"2019-35":0,"2019-36":0,"2019-37":30974.6,"2019-38":7766.5,"2019-39":7685,"2019-40":21128.7,"2019-41":28996,"2019-42":46362.6,"2019-43":0,"2019-44":0,"2019-45":63694.8,"2019-46":81551.1,"2019-47":104595.9,"2019-48":18121.7,"2019-49":18691.6,"2019-50":37538,"2019-51":40671.8,"2019-52":22109.6,"2020-01":22079,"2020-02":22086.7,"2020-03":21933.2,"2020-04":30702.1,"2020-05":58259,"2020-06":38811.3,"2020-07":43754,"2020-08":45109.1,"2020-09":50870.1,"2020-10":62917.8,"2020-11":0,"2020-12":95912.5,"2020-13":20836.2,"2020-14":25293,"2020-15":110540.5,"2020-16":150804.9}}]

How do I structure my data so I can feed my chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `series.data` needs to be an array of arrays or an array of objects. Now it is an object.

```
data: [
    [0, 6],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 6]
]
```

Or:

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 9
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4977/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data